# Making unison ignore file property differences

Tags: sync, rsync, unison, ignore

I'm trying to use unison (the GUI) to synchronize two folders; unfortunately, one of them is a Windows drive mountpoint with properties set to 0777 - and unison shows that as a difference which requires synchronization.

How can I make unison (specifically, the GUI) ignore these property differences and only look at the rest of the criteria (dates, sizes etc.?)

Comment: According to unison documentations - incompatible permissions between different systems aren't synced. The same applied to unix's user/groups, but since it is mapped drive you should set the same permissions in both locations or use unison instance on windows itself. Unison actually officially abounded project. I suggest you to try "syncthing", it is single file without any dependencies and compiled practically for all well know operation systems.

Comment: According to this page https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/status.html Unison is still maintained and new versions are released... they only say that "Unison is no longer under active development as a research project."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As indicated in the [Preferences section](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/blob/525cb8bb2252df6ba83ac49a609a0f35e438c3d7/unison-manual.txt#L1021) of the Unison User Manual and Reference Guide, you can set:

```
perms=0
dontchmod=true
```

in your preferences file (`.prf`).

On a computer running OS X, you can find these .prf-files in the directory */Users/username/Library/Application Support/Unison/*

Comment: perms = 0 means: do not synchronize permissions.